# Eigenvalues of idempotent in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, notation

I have been given the following task:

Let $T\in\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be an idempotent.

1) What are the possible eigenvalues of $T$?

2) Find examples in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ showing that the potential eigenvalues can be realized.

My answer to the first question:

A linear map, $T\in End(V)$ is called idempotent if $T^2=T$. then:
$$ Tv=\lambda v\Longrightarrow T^2v=\lambda Tv=\lambda^2v$$
And using the condition for an idempotent we then have:
$$T^2 v=Tv=\lambda^2v\Longrightarrow\lambda=\lambda^2$$
And it follows that the eigenvalues can be either $0$ or $1$.

Now for the second question, I do not know what the notation $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ means, and therefore do not know how to tackle that question.

Comment: $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ is the set of square matrices with real entries of dimension $n$.

Comment: Ah, great. That solves it.